# Highlight A Control On A Specific Subform Record

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form (called `frmMain`) with a subform control (called `subFrmSub`) that is linked to the form `frmSub`.

`frmSub`'s `Default View` property is set to `Continuous Forms`.  `frmSub` contains several controls that the user can tab to.

What I would like to do is when the user tabs to a control in a specific instance of `frmSub`, that specific instance of the control is highlighted by setting the `Border Style` property to `Solid`.  No instance of that control from other instances of `frmSub` should be so highlighted.

I have tried searching for a solution to this problem in the Access context, but even the best ones result in all instances of the control being highlighted.

The best I have come up with is the following code, which also highlights the entire collection of that control rather than the specific one...

```
Private Sub cmd02_GotFocus()
    Me.cmd02.BorderStyle = 1
End Sub
```

Is it possible to highlight the specific control, and if so, then how?  If not, then why not?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can't set unbound controls individually. You may be able to use Conditional Formatting for this.

Comment: ^^ This. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-appearance-of-a-control-by-using-conditional-formatting-6ba9e9fa-4347-4183-b335-44e43b05e22f#bmfieldhasfocus

Comment: i haven't looked at continuous forms for a while but i think they're like clones, so doing something to one means doing it to all of them. there might be a way but i'm not sure right now.